# using lambdas makes JSF to crash

Tags: jsf, java-8

I just have found probably unexpected behaviour I need so solve.

If I use Lambdas in a getter of the managed-bean of the current view, I get following error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'logbookOperationsBean' resolved to null
viewId=/logbookOperations.xhtml
....
phaseId=PROCESS_VALIDATIONS(3)
Caused by:
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException - Target Unreachable, identifier 'logbookOperationsBean' resolved to null
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:74)
```

by using this line:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(changes)) {
    changes.stream().forEach((element) -> System.out.println(element));
}
```

When I remove the Lambda and replace it with the 'old' version:

```
changes.stream().forEach(new Consumer<TreeNode>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(final TreeNode element) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
});
```

everything works fine.

Any Ideas why?

I am using Tomcat 8 and JRE1.8.0_71

Comment: That exception is unlikely to be related to lambada expressions in Java 8. Are you implying that the application worked normally, if the `Stream`s used were replaced by usual `for` loops.

Comment: You'll get this if the getter throws a runtime exception to afaik, so maybe try to see what happens if you wrap the code in the getter in a try/catch block

Comment: The only difference between working and nonworking is the use of the lamda Expression as explained.the bean which is not found any more is the bean containing the getter (which ruturns just a string for the view). So it must rely on lamda? Even the stream() is used in the working counterpart

Comment: You don’t need a stream to call `forEach` for a collection. You can use just `changes.forEach(…)`. Besides that, when the lambda expression makes a difference, check the exact version of your framework and libraries and their Java 8 compatibility status.